# Connect speaker directly to Samsung Galaxy S6. Minimum impedance accepted

Tags: current, amplifier, impedance, speakers, telephone

I want to connect an external (passive) speaker (3W/16 ohm) directly to my Samsung Galaxy S6 using the headphone jack. I want to do this on my bicycle **using the smallest space possible**. Connecting the phone to an active speaker requires extra space (speaker + rechargeable batteries + amplifier pbc) so reusing phone's amplifier will be the optimal solution.

Is the impedance too small? What is the minimum impedance that I can use? Is 16 ohm safe?

Comment: You'd need the specifications of the phone to determine that.  Practically speaking, while no one other than the vendor can make any promises, there's a reasonable chance you would get away with it - a single 16 ohm speaker is a comparable load to two 32 ohm headphones with a Y adapter, for example, and if that broke phones it would seem likely that people would complain.   Absent specs from the vendor you could try to identify the headphone amp from a teardown writeup, or look at data sheets of other headphone amps sold for such purposes.

Comment: Most probably in the hundreds of ohms.

Comment: 50 Ohms minimum IMO although this test was 16 Ohms Not sure about Pd issues.  https://forum.xda-developers.com/s7-edge/how-to/s7-edge-headphone-output-measurements-t3336123

Comment: They said Zout 5.6 Ohm which ought to be <<2% of speaker load.

Comment: The headphones that ship with the device have a 32-ohm impedance, it appears.

https://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-hs-330-earphones-with-mic-eohs3303lesta/specs/

Comment: Have you considered plugging the phone into either a set of external PC speakers or the line input of a soundcard /laptop?

Comment: @PaulUszak - yes. of course. sure. naturally - see my updated question :)

Comment: 2 li-po batteries and a class-d module off ebay will drive 10 W into 8 ohms with minimal effort

Comment: Because there's such a large market for active speakers, there's a lot of competition to get them as portable as possible (and cheap)  So they're not necessarily any bigger than the actual speakers inside plus just enough material to protect the cones. The amp and batteries fit around the speakers (plural as they're normally stereo).  If you could draw 3W from your phone, the battery wouldn't last very long - a replacement for my phone is 9Wh and that's not just powering your speakers

Comment: @ChrisH-I already made a circuit (in a small box) that is powering the phone from my bike hub dynamo. I would like to put the speaker in there. I don't have a lot of room. It looks like I have to move the circuit in a new box to accommodate the amplifier.